# Logstash filter to convert "$epoch.$microsec" to "$epoch_millis"

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to convert a timestamp field that is in the form `$epoch.$microsec` to `$epoch_millis`.

Example:

```
1415311569.541062  -->  1415311569541
```

Logstash doesn't appear to have any means of multiplying numbers so `ts * 1000` and casting to a long is out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In your particular case you can indeed get away with turning the problem into a string manipulation problem, but you can also use the `ruby` filter:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    # do some calculation
    code => "event['ts'] = (1000 * event['ts'].to_f).round"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what ended up working.

```
mutate {
        convert => { 
            "ts" => "string"
        }

        gsub => [
            "ts", "\.", "",
            "ts", "\d{3}$", ""
        ]
}
```

```