# Getting elasticsearch to utilize Bro timestamps through Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, logstash-grok

I'm having some issues getting elasticsearch to interpret an epoch millis timestamp field.  I have some old bro logs I want to ingest and have them be in the proper orders and spacing.  Thanks to [Logstash filter to convert "$epoch.$microsec" to "$epoch_millis"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790543/logstash-filter-to-convert-epoch-microsec-to-epoch-millis/31753305#31753305)
I've been able to convert the field holding the bro timestamp to the proper length of digits.  I've also inserted a mapping into elasticsearch for that field, and it says that the type is "Date" with the format being the default.  However, when I go and look at the entries it still has a little "t" next to it instead of a little clock.  And hence I can't use it for my filter view reference in kibana.

Anyone have any thoughts or have dealt with this before?  Unfortunately it's a stand alone system so I would have to manually enter any of the configs I'm using.

I did try and convert my field "ts" back to an integer after using the method described in the link above.  So It should be a logstash integer before hitting the elasticsearch mapping.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just deleting all my mappings in Kibana, and elasticsearch.  I then resubmitted and this time it worked.  Must have been some old junk in there that was messing me up.  But now it's working great!